# Which ggplot2 functions do I need to import for a package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package

I am currently writing a package which utilizes ggplot2's S3 generic autoplot but I am unsure which functions I should be importing from ggplot2?

Say I have the following function:

```
tmp = function (n) {
  data = data.frame(x = rnorm(n, 0, 1))
  structure(list(data = data),
            class = "tmp")
}
```

And I wish to plot this data with the following function:

```
autoplot.tmp = function (object, ...) {
  ggplot(object$data, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram()
}
```

I can then obviously run this with the following code:

```
my_data = tmp(100)
autoplot(my_data)
```

So my question is, when I am building `autoplot.tmp` into my package, and I use the `@importFrom ggplot2` command, which functions should I import? Is `aes` a function which needs to be imported, for example? And do I need to import the `autoplot` function itself?

Comment: Although it is nice to import only the needed functions, I would probably just use `@import ggplot2` and be done with it with respect to packages like ggplot2 where there are many functions that are interdependent.

Comment: Cool thanks. That's what I had been doing but for some reason I had got it stuck in my head that I needed to import individual functions.

Comment: No worries, unless someone else corrects me, importing specific functions is to avoid conflicts between other functions with the same names.  `ggplot2` is very unique so you probably don't need to worry about any conflicts.

Comment: Ah I see thanks. I did wonder what the difference was. I thought it was a memory thing haha...